# How can I assign values in the form 'void' to variables in the form 'char'?

Tags: c++, stack, std

I'm creating a program using a stack to make sure the parenthesis order is correct.
But a small error holds me back.
's1.pop()' cannot be assigned to the variable 'open_ch'.
I tried the function 'malloc', but I couldn't stop the error.
This error makes me tired. What is the solution to this error?

```
int check_matching_STL(const char* in)
{   stack <int> s1;
    char ch, open_ch;
    int i, n = strlen(in);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ch = in[i];
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '(': case '[': case '{':
        s1.push(ch);
        break;

    case ')': case ']': case '}':
        if (s1.empty())
            return 0;
        else
        {
            open_ch = s1.pop(); // error

            if ((open_ch == '(' && ch != ')') ||
                (open_ch == '[' && ch != ']') ||
                (open_ch == '{' && ch != '}'))
                return 0;

            break;
        }
    }
}
if (!s1.empty())
    return 0;
return 1;
```

}

Comment: `pop()` doesn't return anything. `void` represents the absence of an object. You need `top()` to get the top object before you pop it off the stack.

Comment: yep, reading documentation about data structures you use is a nice thing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop  &&   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top

Comment: Thank you all for answering my questions! I was very nervous in writing the first question, but thank you for your kind answer! Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

`std::stack::pop` removes the top element from the stack.
i think you was searching for `std::stack::top` instead.

```
open_ch = s1.top(); //getting top element
s1.pop(); //removing top element
```

and i think you should also change your `std::stack<int>` to `std::stack<char>` to make your purpose clearer and avoid useless implicit casts `int` to `char` and `char` to `int` that could push out warnings.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my questions! I was very nervous in writing the first question, but thank you for your kind answer! Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem!

Comment: @김찬하 FYI: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Please, note the emphasized sentence in the link. ;-)

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to use a `std::stack<char>` but there are no casts that it would avoid. Given the values are all in range, `int` and `char` implicitly convert to each other without issue

Comment: using `char open_ch = s1.top();` (with s1.top() returning an int or const int&) the compiler could push out a warning : implicit 'cast -int- to -char- possible losing of data'